# How to check if user is a member of crossdomain group in ldap?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have two AD domain: domain1 и domain2.
I created group GlobalGroup inside domain1, and added another group Domain1Group inside GlobalGroup. 
I have two users: user1 и user2 and group Domain2Group in domain2.
 
Between domain1 and domain2 was set two-way trust. And I added Domain2Group in GlobalGroup.
 
User1 is a member of Domain1Group, and user2 is a member of Domain2Group.
So now I need to check if they both are members of GlobalGroup.

[Here](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/09/13/one-user-is-member-of-a-group.html) I found how to find if user is member of some group from another domain.
My function (below) works perfectly for user1. For user2 it returns false.

GroupPrincipal.GetMemebers(true) will return user2, but it is very slow (minutes on prod) and I can't use it.

What did I miss? Is it in code or in domain's settings?

Code sample:

```
private static bool IsUserInGroup(UserPrincipal user, DirectoryEntry group, bool recursive)
        {
            group.RefreshCache(new[] {"distinguishedName", "groupType"});
            var recursiveFilter = recursive ? ":1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:" : "";
            var filter = string.Format("(member{0}={1})", recursiveFilter, user.DistinguishedName);
            var groupDN = (string)group.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;

            if (((int)group.Properties["groupType"].Value & 8) == 0)
            {
                var groupDomainDN = groupDN.Substring(groupDN.IndexOf(",DC=", StringComparison.Ordinal));
                filter = string.Format("(|{0}(member{1}=CN={2}, CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals{3}))", filter, recursiveFilter, user.Sid, groupDomainDN);
            }

            var searcher = new DirectorySearcher
            {
                Filter = filter,
                SearchRoot = group,
                PageSize = 1,
                SearchScope = SearchScope.Base
            };

            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            return searcher.FindOne() != null;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of that article you found. :)

What is the scope of your parent group? You call it `GlobalGroup`, but Global groups cannot have members from other domains. So it must be either Universal (if the two domains are in the same AD forest) or Domain Local. The answer will be different in each case.

I will assume the two domains are not in the same forest and the group is Domain Local.

The code will only return true is the external user is a *direct member* of the group.

If you use that code to check if `Domain2Group` is a member of `GlobalGroup`, it would return `true`. But when you use it to check if `user2` is a member, it's not looking inside `Domain2Group` to see if the user is there.

This is something I should address, so I have updated the code in my article. We can use the `tokenGroups` attribute of the user to get a recursive list of all groups the user is in. That gives us a list of SIDs. So we can use that to look for any of those groups in our parent group on the other domain.

I see you have your `user` object as a `UserPrincipal`. To pass it into this method, you can use [`user.GetUnderlyingObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getunderlyingobject?view=netframework-4.7.2), like this:

```
IsUserInGroup((DirectoryEntry) user.GetUnderlyingObject(), group, true)
```

Here is the updated method:

```
private static bool IsUserInGroup(DirectoryEntry user, DirectoryEntry group, bool recursive) {

    //fetch the attributes we're going to need
    user.RefreshCache(new [] {"distinguishedName", "objectSid"});
    group.RefreshCache(new [] {"distinguishedName", "groupType"});

    //This magic number tells AD to look for the user recursively through any nested groups
    var recursiveFilter = recursive ? ":1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:" : "";

    var userDn = (string) user.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;
    var groupDn = (string) group.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;

    var filter = $"(member{recursiveFilter}={userDn})";

    if (((int) group.Properties["groupType"].Value & 8) == 0) {
        var groupDomainDn = groupDn.Substring(
            groupDn.IndexOf(",DC=", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        var userDomainDn = userDn.Substring(
            userDn.IndexOf(",DC=", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        if (groupDomainDn != userDomainDn) {
            //It's a Domain Local group, and the user and group are on
            //different domains, so the account might show up as a Foreign
            //Security Principal. So construct a list of SID's that could
            //appear in the group for this user
            var fspFilters = new StringBuilder();

            var userSid =
                new SecurityIdentifier((byte[]) user.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);
            fspFilters.Append(
                $"(member{recursiveFilter}=CN={userSid},CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals{groupDomainDn})");

            if (recursive) {
                //Any of the groups the user is in could show up as an FSP,
                //so we need to check for them all
                user.RefreshCache(new [] {"tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal"});
                var tokenGroups = user.Properties["tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal"];
                foreach (byte[] token in tokenGroups) {
                    var groupSid = new SecurityIdentifier(token, 0);
                    fspFilters.Append(
                        $"(member{recursiveFilter}=CN={groupSid},CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals{groupDomainDn})");
                }
            }
            filter = $"(|{filter}{fspFilters})";
        }
    }

    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher {
        Filter = filter,
        SearchRoot = group,
        PageSize = 1, //we're only looking for one object
        SearchScope = SearchScope.Base
    };

    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn"); //just so it doesn't load every property

    return searcher.FindOne() != null;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect your answer. And thank you very much! It works and works fast.

Comment: I'm new with Active Directory and didn't know about "tokenGroups" so I'm especially grateful for your explanations.
Is "tokenGroups" will always return full list of SIDs? Could be here some hidden problems?

Comment: `tokenGroups` is used for permissions. So it has all groups that the user should get permissions from. It has all the groups the user is a member of, and any groups those groups are members of, etc. The only trick is that it will not show distribution lists (where the "Group type" is "Distribution"). It will only show Security groups.

Comment: If you have some distribution groups, you could use [`tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-tokengroupsglobalanduniversal) instead of `tokenGroups`, since it will include distribution groups. But that might only exist if you are using Exchange, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I think I prefer using `tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal`. I updated it. I also realized it should only be used when `recursive` is `true`, so I fixed that too.

Comment: thanks again, you're a savior. We don't using Exchange now, but it's good to have as much information as I can find.